# Overwrite taxonomy/term page with custom view isn't working

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to style my `taxonomy/term` page and as it turns out, a lot of people are trying to do this. Internet is filled with tutorials and how-to-guides, but for some reason, it seems I'm doomed and not able to do so.

I've installed the Taxonomy Display module and I *think* my settings are all good:

[image]

And my view is configured with the taxonomy arguments:

[image]

But still, the `products/tents` (aka taxonomy/3) doesn't take the View style I've configured... What am I overlooking here?

When I take a look at my live preview of my view, it seems everything is right. Only something looks overwritten on my website because there it doesn't take over the Views layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind

1. The taxonomy path is normally taxonomy/term/% ( not taxonomy/% )
2. Views ships with a default taxonomy/term/% override ( just needs enabling )

Perhaps that will help.

Comment: Thx for your help. I've tried your number 1, but still with no results... The default taxonomy override is not sufficient enough for my purposes I'm afraid.

Comment: I usually use the default taxonomy/term/% view, change the path to views/taxonomy/term/% and embed it in the default taxonomy_term Panels page.